# Suspected illegal access to mac

Tags: macos, security

I have a situation at hand; I am running Mac OS X 10.8.4.

Today I observed a different icon [image: strangeicon] on my Mac status bar. When I clicked on it it showed the name of computer of our vendor organization (a few members sit in our office).  My bluetooth was on and I am connected to the LAN.

I searched on the net but couldn't find what this symbol means and if there was any attempt to get illegal access to my Mac. I have pretty sensitive data. Please help; if there was any access how can I see the log?

Comment: It is the Apple Air Display icon; it just means there is an Apple TV or other device in your network that supports acting as a remote display for your computer. It does **not** mean your computer has been hacked.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Can it be used to take screen shot of my computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icon you see is the [Airplay icon](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5404); it simply means that there is a device in your network that supports Airplay and can be used as a remote screen.

This is a standard feature of OS X, in combination with other products, like an Apple TV device. It does **not** mean your computer is compromised. Most likely someone on your network is running [Air Display](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/air-display/id419449718?mt=12) or similar software to act as a Airplay-compatible screen.

You are still in full control, only if you were to activate the feature would your screen be mirrored on the Airplay device.